# Stop / Start network in autohotkey without needing to be an administrator

Tags: windows, autohotkey, netsh

I'm trying to map out via AutoHotkey a keyboard shortcut to enable / disable windows networking.

I found online this solution:

```
ConnectedToTheInternet(flag=0x40) {
    Return DllCall("Wininet.dll\InternetGetConnectedState", "Str", flag, "Int", 0)
}

+T::
    
    adapter := "Local Area Connection" ; Adapter Name
    
    if ConnectedToTheInternet()
        runwait,netsh interface set interface "%adapter%" admin=disabled,,hide
    else
        runwait,netsh interface set interface "%adapter%" admin=enabled,,hide
    return

return
```

Using Shift + T as test hotkey, it seems to work but only if is in Admin mode otherwise netsh dosn't work. Instead of running AutoHotkey script in admin mode, if I go in control panel and right click on the network interface disabling it, it just disable/enable it without asking any admin privileges.

There's something else that I can use instead of netsh in order to bring down/up network interfaces so that I could not need the administrative privileges ?

EDIT:
I'm a bit disappointed. I'm considering to write a routine to open the Network and Sharing center (see pic below) and automatically click to enable/disable the interface and close automatically the window but would be not so nice to see each time.

[image: Windows Control Panel - Network Connections]

Otherwise I would have to write a service listening on a socket only to being interfaced with my script, a simple c# service that do only the wmic or netsh command with admin privileges without having to privilege with admin the whole AutoHotkey script...

Answer (score 1):

Use WMIC.

**Enable interface:**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where "netconnectionid like '%Local Area Connection%'" call enable
```

**Disable interface:**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where "netconnectionid like '%Local Area Connection%'" call disable
```

You can type directly these commands in command prompt. Integrate them in AutoHotKeys is then trivial.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter

Comment: Hi Wisblade, it works but only in administrator mode sadly. I edited the question with some ideas but doing it in some sort of way via command line would be lot more easy, and portable.

Comment: @user3450548 What?? Quite strange, it works in non-elevated mode on my computer... Or, at least, it doesn't whine about any missing privilege, and usually on Windows you're always warned about that. Are you using a pure standard account, or an account which belongs to `Administrators` group with an UAC password-free prompt when needed?

Comment: Using a normal windows7 user account with administrator privileges and uac request on needed. But it doesn't ask me not even a password it silently drops the command, to be specific: If I use a cmd prompt without the administrator it doesn't work. Replies status 5, if I run a cmd with administrator wich brings me a uac, in that case with the cmd elevated, if I write and run that command, the status is 0 and the enabling/disabling of the interface works... It could be possible that you have different Local Group Policy in Control Panel -> Administrators Tools that make this behave differently ?

Comment: @user3450548 Possible, I tweaked several things on my OS. But it shouldn't do that. You'll need to run a service with privileges (or a scheduled task when opening session) in order to get an elevated process which can be requested from user land. It's not so difficult, tutorials for that are easily found.